# MongoDB - Find users by Name or Surname or Name+Surname

Tags: mongodb, find, concatenation

I'm trying to replicate this SQL query in MongoDB :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
name LIKE CONCAT('%', :search_txt, '%') OR
surname LIKE CONCAT('%', :search_txt, '%') OR
CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE CONCAT('%', :search_txt, '%')
```

So far i managed to search by name or surname with this code but i can't figure out how to search also by name+surname

```
User.find(
 { 
  "$or": [
          {"name" : new RegExp(req.body.term, 'i')},
          {"surname" : new RegExp(req.body.term, 'i')}
        ]
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the SQL query work when names are entered as Surname + Name? does it work when there are 2 spaces between names?

Comment: @Alex Blex I only wrote it like that to make it as simple as possible, in the original project where I was using it, I also had another OR to cover the Surname+Name case.

Comment: The better option here is to "split" the string and send the arguments to `$or` as distinct words. Regex matches or concatenation require a "full collection scan", but providing "exact match" terms does not and is therefore orders of magnitude faster. Also you really should normalize case, or use case insensitive indexes if your MongoDB supports it. Avoid case insensitive regular expressions or calculated expressions if you want to keep query response time to a minimum.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, I will definitely refactor the code to use your approach.
I need a little help to do so : How can I add arguments to the $or basing on an array of unknown size ? (For example if the name and surname has more than two words I would have an array with more than two elements, so I could not hard code the first two index of it)

Comment: @Nite You would use `.split()` for JavaScript to break up the words by the spaces in between, and you can always look send each "list" as an `$in` argument inside each `$or` ( or even various "or" expressions, but `$in` would be shorter. If you still don't understand that then you should [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so you can express clearly and have that specific question answered. I will note though that separate `$project` or `$addFields` stages to a `$match` is actually even causing more performance problems than even the calculation itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
User.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "fullname": {
            $concat: [ "$name", ' ', "$surname" ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "$or": [
            {"name": new RegExp(req.body.term, 'i')},
            {"surname": new RegExp(req.body.term, 'i')},
            {"fullname": new RegExp(req.body.term, 'i')}
        ]        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works.
I had to add [ ] to avoid the "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators" error.

Comment: Yeah, depending on your client that may be required. My code works from within the Robomongo console.